# Помогите с решением

Tags: python, python-3.x

Дано натуральное число. Напишите программу, которая вычисляет:

1. сумму его цифр;
2. количество цифр в нем;
3. произведение его цифр;
4. среднее арифметическое его цифр;
5. его первую цифру;
6. сумму его первой и последней цифры.

Формат входных данных
На вход программе подается одно натуральное число.

Формат выходных данных

Программа должна вывести значения указанных величин в указанном порядке.

```
INPUT

5678
OUTPUT

26
4
1680
6.5
5
13
```

МОЙ ОТВЕТ:

```
n = int(input())
m = 1
print(sum(map(0, n)))
print(len(n))
while n > 0:
    m *= n % 10
    n = n // 10
print(m)
print(sum(map(int, n)) / len(n))
print(n[0])
print(int(n[0]) + int(n[-1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Предложу чуть другой вариант. Не приводите ввод к цифрам он вам в начале мешает.

```py
n = input() # Получите строку

l = [] # в l получите список цифр
for i in x:
    l.append(int(i)) # Получаем число
```

А дальше почти все вычислений в принт можно писать сразу. Только с произведением чуть подумать. Например `print("Среднее арифм:", sum(l)/len(l))`. Если возникнут вопросы дополню.

Answer (score 1):

Идея правильная, исполнение не очень

1. сначала сформируйте список цифр и от этого пляшите

   ```
    value = int(input())

    digits = []

    while value != 0:
        digits.append(value % 10)
        value //= 10
   ```
2. а дальше работайте со списком как хотите, например

сумма первой и последней цифр:

```
res = digits[0] + digits[-1]
```

правда надо учесть ситуацию, когда всего 1 цифра в числе

```
res = (digits[0] + digits[-1]) if len(digits) > 1 else digits[0]
```

**P.S.**

кстати список цифр можно получить так (без всяких `while` в 1 строчку):

```
digits = list(map(int, str(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот так можно:

```
n = list(map(int, input()))
_sum = sum(n)
_len = len(n)
f = 1
for x in n:
    f *= x

print(_sum)
print(_len)
print(f)
print(_sum/_len)
print(n[0])
print(n[0]+n[1] if _len > 1 else 0)
```

Comment: Error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "jailed_code", line 6, in <module>
    f *= n
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'

Comment: @Егор исправил. опечатался чутка